# Вычисление по всему DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Нужно пересчитать заданный DataFrame в другой валюте:

```
rate = {'RUB': 69.183071}
```

df1:

```
   id val1  val2    val3
    a  100   200    300
    b  500   700    100
    c  1000  1500   2000
```

Нужно получить df2 в другой валюте по rate, грубо говоря значения в DataFrame разделить на rate:

df2:

```
id val1  val2    val3
a  1.44   2.89   4.33
b  7.22   10.11   1.44
c  14.45  21.68   28.91
```

Пытался сделать через `apply lambda`, но почему-то все применимо только к столбцу и выдает мне `Series`. Через `groupby` что-то тоже не получается.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [73]: (df2.set_index("id") / rate["RUB"]).reset_index()
Out[73]:
  id       val1       val2       val3
0  a   1.445440   2.890881   4.336321
1  b   7.227202  10.118082   1.445440
2  c  14.454403  21.681605  28.908806
```

или:

```
In [74]: df2.set_index("id").div(rate["RUB"]).reset_index()
Out[74]:
  id       val1       val2       val3
0  a   1.445440   2.890881   4.336321
1  b   7.227202  10.118082   1.445440
2  c  14.454403  21.681605  28.908806
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! Как и всегда все очень просто и очень красиво!